# PHP Forms to update a SQLite3 database

Tags: php, forms, sqlite

I need some help I am trying to create a PHP form using sqlite3 and I keep on getting a "syntax error, unexpected T_CATCH in post.php on line 10". All I want to do from the php form is update an existing sqlite3 database in the table1 where the column type = p and the column id = 340 with the values from the form.

### HTML Code:

```
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>Update Form</title>
   </head>
   <body style="font-size:12;font-family:verdana">
   <form action="post.php" method="post">
   <p>
   Slot1: <input type="text" name="slot1"><br>
   Slot2: <input type="text" name="slot2"><br>
   </p>

   <p>
   <input type="submit" name="update" value="update">
   </p>

   </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

### PHP Code: Post.php

```
<?php
$slot1 = sqlite_escape_string($_POST['slot1']);
$slot2 = sqlite_escape_string($_POST['slot2']);

try
{
$db = new PDO("sqlite:DefaultLibrary.db");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
catch(Exception $e)
{   
echo $e->getMessage();
}
}
if (!empty($slot1)) {
try
{   
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE tabel1 SET Slot1Pos = :slot1, Slot2Pos = :slot2 WHERE Type = P and ID = 340");
    $stmt->bindParam(':slot1', $slot1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':slot2', $slot2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute()
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}

echo "Form submitted successfully";

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a brace:

```
try {
    $db = new PDO("sqlite:DefaultLibrary.db");
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
} catch(Exception $e) {   
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: yeah, i agree. indenting properly/consistently makes all the difference in the world sometimes.